# Изменение шаблона регулярки

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть паттерн `~//(.+?)//~s`, но нужно сделать, чтобы он не ловил `http://site`, то есть не срабатывал когда перед `//` идёт `:`.

Как можно это сделать?

Comment: `~` - это ограничители? `s` - это флаг?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте блок предварительного просмотра назад `(?<!:)` (*найди совпадение, если слева от текущей позиции нет `:`*):

```
~(?<!:)//(.+?)//~s
```

[Демо](https://regex101.com/r/hnDUKI/1)

В PHP есть возможность отлавливать нежелательные совпадения и отсеивать их с помощью `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`:

```
~\b(https?|ftps?)://(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|//(.+?)//~s
```

[Ещё одно демо](https://regex101.com/r/hnDUKI/2)

Т.е. находим `\b(https?|ftps?)://`, границу слова, протоколы и `://`, а потом  `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` удаляют это совпадение из буфера, и следующее совпадение ищется с конца предыдущего совпадения.